# D3: zoom to bounds with TopoJSON mesh

Tags: javascript, d3.js, topojson

I am trying to implement a 'zoom to bound' feature on my D3 map. This is the Block that I have in mind:

https://bl.ocks.org/iamkevinv/0a24e9126cd2fa6b283c6f2d774b69a2

My issue is that it looks like the implementation requires a topoJSON mesh. I am unsure what that is, and how to tweak my code to add one. This is how I currently populate my map:

```
var mediumRes = g.append("g")
    .attr("id", "country-mediumRes");

d3.json("medium-res.json", function(collection) {
    mediumRes.selectAll("path")
    .data(collection.features)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "country-mediumRes")
    .attr("d", path);
});
```

To calculate the path.bounds for my countries, it looks like my code would need a mesh. In the block, I think it pertains to this line of code:

```
g.append("path")
    .datum(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
    .attr("class", "mesh")
    .attr("d", path);
```

How do I amend my code so that the topoJSON mesh is created properly? Incidentally, What does the mesh do?

Comment: You don't need the mesh, that's just for the states' strokes. Have a look at this bl.ocks without mesh: http://bl.ocks.org/GerardoFurtado/075ee5c2267c0b2fd231651e39ea7791

Comment: Hello Gerardo - thanks for your comment and sharing your block. The reason is I tried to add the mesh is because I assumed I needed topoJSON to get this to work. I keep on getting the following error message: `Uncaught TypeError: path.bounds is not a function`

Comment: Is the error that I must be loading a topoJSON as opposed to a geoJSON? What if my data isn't a topoJSON, how can I zoom to the bounding box? I still don't understand why I am getting this error, and the reason why the path.bounds function isn't recognized.

Comment: The bounds aren't calculated using the mesh - the bounds are calculated using the geojson feature that was clicked on. As @GerardoFurtado states, the mesh is just for strokes in this example. You *could* zoom to the mesh* (as with any other geojson feature(s)) as the mesh is just geojson once created, but it would be an unnecessary complication, also as meshes are polylines, not polygons, mouse events won't work as anticipated, even with fill (as each border segment is filled, not each geographical unit). **You could zoom to the mesh as a whole, individual polygons would be quite difficult*